# How to use this module on my Ionic project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am just starting using Ionic framework recently. I have been trying to import this vcard module.

https://github.com/Heymdall/vcard

I am able to use it in normal javascript environment, but so far I am not able to use it in my .ts file.

What I have done are:

1. Adding the module using

   > npm install vcard-parser --save
   >  
   >   npm install ajv@>=5.0.0 --save
2. Import it inside .ts file

   > import * as v from 'vcard-parser'
3. Then this is the result from console.log(v)

   > Object {}
   >   **proto**
   >   :
   >   Object
   >   constructor
   >   :
   >   function Object()
   >   hasOwnProperty
   >   :
   >   function hasOwnProperty()
   >   isPrototypeOf
   >   :
   >   function isPrototypeOf()
   >   propertyIsEnumerable
   >   :
   >   function propertyIsEnumerable()
   >   toLocaleString
   >   :
   >   function toLocaleString()
   >   toString
   >   :
   >   function ()
   >   valueOf
   >   :
   >   function valueOf()
   >   **defineGetter**
   >   :
   >   function **defineGetter**()
   >   **defineSetter**
   >   :
   >   function **defineSetter**()
   >   **lookupGetter**
   >   :
   >   function **lookupGetter**()
   >   **lookupSetter**
   >   :
   >   function **lookupSetter**()
   >   get **proto**
   >   :
   >   function **proto**()
   >   set **proto**
   >   :
   >   function **proto**()

I don't know how to use the module, such as calling function "parse" or "generate".

Could anybody please help me with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

So their documentation on the install is not quite correct.

```
npm install vcard-parser
```

should change to

```
npm install vcard-parser --save
```

To save it to your `package.json`

I not 100% but it does not look like the code conforms to the component -> module pattern ( might be wrong here, just looks a bit different )

For most ionic/angular extentions/components you want to import it in your `app.module.ts` using the name declared in the `package.json`.

for example *ionic-network* would be

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
```

Because in the `package.json` it is declared as a dependency as

```
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.1.0",
```

You can also import for a specific page and add it to the constructor.

Here is a post from the official documentation on [installing 3rd party libraries](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/)

Comment: Hi arkade, thanks for the help. I have tried that, but so far no luck as well. I've edited my question to provide more progress detail.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [how is vcard-parser tested](https://github.com/Heymdall/vcard/blob/master/test/vcard.parse.spec.js), it should be like this:

```
declare var require: any;
var vCard = require('vcard-parser').vCard;
vCard.parse(raw);
```

Comment: That is in JavaScript.. I am using the module in TypeScript.

Comment: it is typescript..the reason why the `require` is used instead of `import` is that `vcard-parser` module has no typescript typings. Doesn't it work?